# How to draw borders around page contents

Tags: margins, tex-core, plain-tex

During learning, while conducting different experiments, it's useful to see actual page borders. So I wrote the code which does this and would like to know whether it is the proper way to accomplish this kind of task.

The code is used like this:

```
\input page_borders
whatever content
\bye
```

This is page_borders.tex

```
% Overload shipout (idea from quire.tex):
\newbox\mybox
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox\mybox=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\setbox\mybox=\vbox{
  % This is the main part:
  \vskip-0.4pt \hrule
  \nointerlineskip
  \moveleft 0.4pt \vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}
  \nointerlineskip
  \kern-\vsize \nobreak
  \nointerlineskip
  \moveright \hsize \vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}
  \nointerlineskip
  \kern-\vsize \nobreak
  \unvbox\mybox
  \hrule
}\shipout\box\mybox}
```

Comment: [Package `framed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) is for LaTeX. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke yes... I saw `\bye` and edit my comment in the last minute. By the way there are other packages (for LaTeX, of course) such as `showframe`. I guess they are just some tricks around boxes so one should be able to translate the code back to plain-TeX.

Answer (score 1):

First `\nointerlineskip` is not necessary, because it follows `\hrule`;
third and fourth `\nointerlineskip`s are not necessary, because they follow a kern.
Also, there is a slight catch here: we must add `width \hsize` to first and fourth `\hrule`, lest top and bottom rules extend out of page boundaries (because of `\moveright \hsize ...` + width 0.4 pt of right margin rule and because `\hrule` takes all available width by default).

So, the page_borders.tex becomes:

```
\newbox\pagebox
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox\pagebox=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\setbox\pagebox=\vbox{
  % This is the main part:
  \kern-0.4pt
  \hrule width \hsize
  \moveleft 0.4pt \vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}
  \nointerlineskip
  \kern-\vsize \nobreak
  \moveright \hsize \vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}
  \kern-\vsize \nobreak
  \unvbox\pagebox
  \hrule width \hsize
}\shipout\box\pagebox}
```

To draw page borders without including the footline, instead use this page_borders.tex:

```
\newbox\pagebox
\newdimen\pagedepth
\def\pagebody{\setbox\pagebox=\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}%
  \vbox{
    \kern-0.4pt
    \hrule width \hsize
    \moveleft 0.4pt \vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern-\vsize \nobreak
    \moveright \hsize \rlap{\vbox{\hrule height 0pt depth \vsize width 0.4pt}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern-\vsize \nobreak
    \box\pagebox
    % back up by current prevdepth before inserting bottom margin, and restore afterwards
    \pagedepth=\prevdepth
    \kern-\pagedepth
    \hrule width \hsize
    \kern-0.4pt
    \prevdepth\pagedepth
  }%
}
```