# How much space is occupied by footline?

Tags: margins, plain-tex

This is said in *TeXbook* about page dimensions:

> Plain TEX sets \vsize=8.9in (not 9in, since \vsize doesn't include the space for page numbers at the bottom of each page)...

According to definition of \makefootline, the space occupied by it is 24pt. According to definition of TeX's pt we get 24/72.27 = 0.3in

According to *TeXbook* space occupied by footline is 0.1in, but it is 0.3in. This implies that bottom margin must be 0.8in, not 1in (how to trace that?).

Besides, it is strange that `\nopagenumbers` leaves 24pt at the bottom of page, because if we don't want page numbers, why do we want extra space? (e.g., headline does not contain anything by default - and it does not hold any extra space) Wouldn't the definition of `\nopagenumbers` be more reasonable if it was `\gdef\makefootline{}`? (in this case also `\vsize` must also probably be increased by 24pt)

These are definitions of `\makefootline` and `\nopagenumbers` from plain.tex, to make the question self-consistent:

```
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\line{\the\footline}}
\def\nopagenumbers{\footline{\hfil}} % blank out the footline
```

The following topics provide additional info:

[How to draw borders around page contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263376/how-to-draw-borders-around-page-contents)
[How is a page produced in the output routine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263538/how-is-a-page-produced-in-the-output-routine)

Comment: Also the headline is set in the one inch top margin.

Comment: @egreg: Why footline is not the same as headline? Where that 8.9in appeared from?

Comment: I guess it appealed to Knuth's tastes.

Comment: @egreg: Too bad he didn't explain his decision. Anyway, from your experience, shouldn't there be any logic behind?

Answer (score 1):

Exercise 23.2 in *The TeXbook* and top of page 253 suggest that `\nopagenumbers` is used mainly in conjunction with setting `\headline`, with `\voffset` set to `2\baselineskip` (i.e., 24pt, exactly the height of `\makefootline`). In this case those extra 24pt, which are introduced by `\makefootline`, are below page contents and are simply invisible - this is why it is sufficient to redefine only `\footline`. Also, maybe `\nopagenumbers` does not suppress those 24pt to make it possible to switch page numbers on/off temporarily, and preserve the same layout across all the pages.

As for 8.9in: The margins include the footline and
the headline. Thus in plain TeX the bottom margin is actually about 0.8-inch.

Here are the calculations:

```
<11-inch paper height> - <1-inch top offset> - 
<\vsize=8.9-inch from plain.tex> - 
<\baselineskip=24pt from the definition of \makefootline>
[ - <the depth of the last line of text> ? ]
= 11 - 1 - 8.9 - 24/72.27 ~ 0.8-inch
```

**EDIT**

The clue is (probably) that `\vsize` is an integral multiple of the `\baselineskip`, meaning
that you will not get warnings if you have a page without any explicit
vertical white space. Most probably `\vsize` was calculated from the number of lines that the author wanted to fit on the page.